# Shimo/Clean My Mac require passwords after messing with sudoers

Tags: macos, mojave, sudo

I messed with sudoers file and sudo was not working. I fixed the issue (booted from recovery mode, mounted root filesystem and fixed permissions) and sudo is now working properly, but after this accident I got some problems with apps like Shimo and CMM X.

Shimo - Can't install helper tools after typing password. (Was working before)

Clean My Mac X - Asks for password every time it needs to delete some file. For example if I want to clean cache I have to type my password 20-40 times.

I have tried re-installing, new copy of macOS and apps as well but same problem.

So how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Clean My Mac will need full disk access in system prefs>security. I've no idea what Shimo might need.

Comment: It has full disk access

Comment: Then I can only guess that whatever permissions you fixed wasn't correct. I'd start by overlaying the OS from Recovery. This should not affect any user files (but always have a backup before you start)

Comment: Is there even a connection between `sudoers` and the problems you see? Can you create a new admin account on your Mac and then start Shimo and Clean My Mac there?

Comment: Yeah because everything was working fine and right after messing with sudoers this problems occurred. I created new user, problem is still same. I added screeshot

Comment: You should only need to clear caches in the event of a problem. Apps like CleanMyMAc are not necessary for the well-ordered running of your Mac, and can cause more problems than good.

Comment: I don't even care if CleanMyMac not gonna work that much, just if this happend to these apps maybe same will happen with another. But I really miss shimo.